# whoami command fails after running /bin/su

Tags: shell, su, init-script, sysvinit

I have a system with an init script that launches multiple applications, each under it's right user and group. The init script checks the home directory of each user and looks for the application init script (/home/user1/init.sh), if found, it runs the following command:

```
/bin/su -c "/home/user1/init.sh start" - user1
```

I added a 'whoami' command at the beginning of the init script, and it fails with an error saying: `whoami - unknown user id XXXX`

The I added a `sleep 5` command before the `whoami` command, ad I got `user1`.

What is the explanation of such behavior, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What does /etc/nsswitch.conf say is used for passwd lookups? The probable explanation is that the script is being called too early in the boot ptocess so the system has not yet set up how lookups should be done (files, ldap, yellow pages, nis+). Which is the `init` script that you added the `wjoami` to, the /home/user1/init or the one which calls it via su?

Comment: I added the whoami to the /home/user1/init, and the init script that calls the 'application's init scripts' is S99.. which is the last script to run.